# gmp compatible alternative to gsl

Tags: c++, gmp, gsl

Up to now I've used the GSL Routines to calculate Eigenvalues/vectors and solve ordinary differential equations (ODEs) in C++.

Now I must use the GNU multiple precision library (GMP), but GSL does not support other datatypes than double.

Does anyone know good alternatives for calculating eigenvalues and solving ODEs which are compatible with the GMP Data Type (mpf_class)?

At the moment I'm thinking about to use the routines provided in the Numerical Recipes. Does anyone know if this is a good idea for my tasks?

Best regards
Dominik

Answer (score 1):

Although clearly not the answer you were hoping for, I would think you could take the hard work of modifying the GSL library to make it compatible with the GMP library. Both are open source, so at least for the license there would be no problem and incidentally I think many would be very grateful. Since the problem is only with the type of data, it would be enough to make a sweep through all the code of the GSL library and to replace the routines one by one. It would not be a fast job but it would be a simple job.